# Exception в Laravel Jobs

Tags: laravel, jobscheduler

Такой вопрос, если в Job или Listener происходит ошибка, а try catch там нет, исключение вернется в условный контроллер/сервис(любое место откуда был вызван Job)? Или нужно отдельно для Job и Listener делать свою обработку?
В добавок вопрос, а что будет при тех же условиях, но если Job выполняется через очереди. Вернется ли эксепшн туда откуда вызван Job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> если в Job или Listener происходит ошибка, а try catch там нет, исключение вернется в условный контроллер/сервис(любое место откуда был вызван Job)?

Да, если у вас настроена синхронная диспетчеризация. Через `sync` драйвер или через метод `dispatchSync`. Иначе нет, т.к. у вас запрос будет не в рамках текущего процесса.

> В добавок вопрос, а что будет при тех же условиях, но если Job выполняется через очереди. Вернется ли эксепшн туда откуда вызван Job?

Нет, не вернется. Это уже другой процесс. Exception упадет в [failed](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#cleaning-up-after-failed-jobs) метод.